# How to pass table's column values to a constructor?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new to java.

I have a hard coded constructor which has parameters from a Class(UserInfo).(As given below)

```
else if (position == menuIndex++) {
                    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(id:1, gender:1, Age:26, Height:163, Weight:63); #Hard Coded Constructor
                    Log.d(TAG, "setUserInfo:" + userInfo.toString() + ",data:" + Arrays.toString(userInfo.getBytes(miband.getDevice().getAddress())));
                    miband.setUserInfo(userInfo);
```

I have created a new activity for the hard coded parameters. I would like to add those parameters(Not Hard Coded) by passing the values entered in the database's table.

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    Gender + " INTEGER, " +
                    Age + " INTEGER , " +
                    Height + " REAL, " +
                    Weight + " REAL,"+
                    Datetime + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ";


My database has values like : 

    User_Id Gender  Age Height  Weight  Datetime
    1   Male    26  163.0   63.0    2020-06-02 10:07:07
```

Could you please help me, how to pass the table values to a Constructor?